# Adding bar button items to nav bar without navigation controller in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to add multiple bar button items to each side of a *custom* nav bar.

I'm using the following method but nothing shows up.

There are a few threads on this in Obj-C but I'm struggling to translate the syntax. Is there a workaround for this in Swift?

```
@IBOutlet weak var navBar: UINavigationBar!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        var iconOne = UIImage(named: "iconOne")
        var iconTwo = UIImage(named: "iconTwo")

        var buttonOne:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: iconOne, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: nil)
        var buttonTwo:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: iconTwo, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: nil)

        self.navBar.setItems([buttonOne,buttonTwo], animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: Start by making sure you're calling `super.viewDidLoad()`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you are using a storyboard, drag a `Navigation Bar`, and drag a `Navigation Item` onto the navigation bar.

[image: storyboard screenshot]

Then connect an `IBOutlet` for your `UINavigationitem`

```
@IBOutlet weak var navItem: UINavigationItem!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let navBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Bookmarks, target: self, action: nil)
    navItem.leftBarButtonItem = navBarButton
}
```

You can also use code:

```
let navbar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 20,
    width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, height: 50))
navbar.tintColor = .lightGray
self.view.addSubview(navbar)

let navItem = UINavigationItem(title: "Test")
let navBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .bookmarks, target: self, action: nil)
navItem.leftBarButtonItem = navBarButton

navbar.items = [navItem]
```

[image: nav bar screenshot]

Comment: Should this be in viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear?

Comment: Any difference semantically?

Comment: `viewDidLoad` will called once in the life circle of Viewcontroller object.`ViewwillApplear` maybe called many times.If you add `subview` in `ViewwillApplear`,it maybe added many times